# C++ , '&&': illegal, right operand has type 'void'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, logical-operators, delete-operator

I downloaded an old project (2008) from codeproject, and now I'm trying to compile it and as a result I'm getting such errors:

```
'&&': illegal, right operand has type 'void'
```

in here:

```
    while( hItem_i )
    {
        PINodeData pNodeData = GetItemData( hItem_i );
        pNodeData && pNodeData->DeleteNodeData() && delete pNodeData; //HERE!!!
....
     }
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Why not using `if()` statements in your code? It would improve the readability also.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid c++ `pNodeData->DeleteNodeData() && delete pNodeData;`

Comment: `void` expression is not allowed as operand of `&&`

Comment: The `delete` expression doesn't return anything, so it can't be used with operators that expects a value. We don't know what `pNodeData->DeleteNodeData()` might return, but if it's declared to return `void` then it have the same problem.

Comment: it's not my code, I just want to compile it and only after that use it

Comment: @Nika_Rika Judging the code quality from the snippet you posted, I'd highly recommend not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `if` is definitely better, you *can* use `&&`:

```
pNodeData && pNodeData->DeleteNodeData() && (delete pNodeData, 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

The error is telling you the problem. `delete` doesn't return anything (and it's highly possible `DeleteNodeData` doesn't either), so it can't be used as part of a test (because the test *must* have a result, even if you don't use it).

Change it to:

```
if (pNodeData) {
    pNodeData->DeleteNodeData();
    delete pNodeData;
}
```

which is the actual logic here (if you have a pointer, clean it up).

Answer (score 4):

You downloaded code that used a short-circuiting hack to skip operations when `pNodeData` is `nullptr`. Unfortunately, this is broken, because `delete` operator has a result of type `void`. It may have worked in the past by exploiting a compiler shortcoming, but it was always non-standard, and should be avoided.

You should rewrite the code as follows:

```
if (pNodeData) {
    pNodeData->DeleteNodeData();
    delete pNodeData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is valid c++. It might have just worked at some point since compilers often will allow for non standard behavior.  The delete does not return anything so how can it be expected to work in and && expression which needs two values convertible to bool.  Why not just change it to something like this...

```
if(pNodeData)
{
    pNodeData->DeleteNodeData();
    delete pNodeData;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`delete pNodeData` is an expression with a `void` type, so therefore it cannot be used as an argument to `&&`.

Assuming that `pNodeData->DeleteNodeData()` is also a `void` type (judging by its name it probably is), consider refactoring to

```
if (PINodeData pNodeData = GetItemData(hItem_i)){
    pNodeData->DeleteNodeData();
    delete pNodeData;
}
```

Note the declaration inside the `if` conditional: this is permitted in the new C++ standards.

It's possible that a previous compiler emitted the original code in error, but that has never been part of standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword `delete`
returns a `void`.
You are evaluating a `bool` expression with a `void`. Only expressions that return `true` or `false` are possible there.

For more information on `delete` visit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/